# Pandas Computing On Multidimensional Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames storing tracking data of offensive and defensive players during an nfl game. My goal is to calculate the maximum distance between an offensive player and the nearest defender during the course of the play.

As a simple example, I've made up some data where there are only three offensive players and two defensive players. Here is the data:

```
Defense
    GameTime  PlayId  PlayerId  x-coord  y-coord
0          1       1       117     20.2     20.0
1          2       1       117     21.0     19.1
2          3       1       117     21.3     18.3
3          4       1       117     22.0     17.5
4          5       1       117     22.5     17.2
5          6       1       117     23.0     16.9
6          7       1       117     23.6     16.7
7          8       2       117     25.1     34.1
8          9       2       117     25.9     34.2
9         10       2       117     24.1     34.5
10        11       2       117     22.7     34.2
11        12       2       117     21.5     34.5
12        13       2       117     21.1     37.3
13        14       3       117     21.2     44.3
14        15       3       117     20.4     44.6
15        16       3       117     21.9     42.7
16        17       3       117     21.1     41.9
17        18       3       117     20.1     41.7
18        19       3       117     20.1     41.3
19         1       1       555     40.1     17.0
20         2       1       555     40.7     18.3
21         3       1       555     41.0     19.6
22         4       1       555     41.5     18.4
23         5       1       555     42.6     18.4
24         6       1       555     43.8     18.0
25         7       1       555     44.2     15.8
26         8       2       555     41.2     37.1
27         9       2       555     42.3     36.5
28        10       2       555     45.6     36.3
29        11       2       555     47.9     35.6
30        12       2       555     47.4     31.3
31        13       2       555     46.8     31.5
32        14       3       555     47.3     40.3
33        15       3       555     47.2     40.6
34        16       3       555     44.5     40.8
35        17       3       555     46.5     41.0
36        18       3       555     47.6     41.4
37        19       3       555     47.6     41.5


Offense 
    GameTime  PlayId  PlayerId  x-coord  y-coord
0          1       1       751     30.2     15.0
1          2       1       751     31.0     15.1
2          3       1       751     31.3     15.3
3          4       1       751     32.0     15.5
4          5       1       751     31.5     15.7
5          6       1       751     33.0     15.9
6          7       1       751     32.6     15.7
7          8       2       751     51.1     30.1
8          9       2       751     51.9     30.2
9         10       2       751     51.1     30.5
10        11       2       751     49.7     30.6
11        12       2       751     49.5     30.9
12        13       2       751     49.1     31.3
13        14       3       751     12.2     40.3
14        15       3       751     12.4     40.5
15        16       3       751     12.9     40.7
16        17       3       751     13.1     40.9
17        18       3       751     13.1     41.1
18        19       3       751     13.1     41.3
19         1       1       419     41.3     15.0
20         2       1       419     41.7     15.3
21         3       1       419     41.8     15.4
22         4       1       419     42.9     15.6
23         5       1       419     42.6     15.6
24         6       1       419     44.8     16.0
25         7       1       419     45.2     15.8
26         8       2       419     62.2     30.1
27         9       2       419     63.3     30.5
28        10       2       419     62.6     31.0
29        11       2       419     63.9     30.6
30        12       2       419     67.4     31.3
31        13       2       419     66.8     31.5
32        14       3       419     30.3     40.3
33        15       3       419     30.2     40.6
34        16       3       419     30.5     40.8
35        17       3       419     30.5     41.0
36        18       3       419     31.6     41.4
37        19       3       419     31.6     41.5
38         1       1       989     10.1     15.0
39         2       1       989     10.2     15.5
40         3       1       989     10.4     15.4
41         4       1       989     10.5     15.8
42         5       1       989     10.6     15.9
43         6       1       989     10.1     15.5
44         7       1       989     10.9     15.3
45         8       2       989     25.8     30.1
46         9       2       989     25.2     30.1
47        10       2       989     21.8     30.2
48        11       2       989     25.8     30.2
49        12       2       989     25.6     30.5
50        13       2       989     25.5     31.0
51        14       3       989     50.3     40.3
52        15       3       989     50.3     40.2
53        16       3       989     50.2     40.4
54        17       3       989     50.1     40.8
55        18       3       989     50.6     41.2
56        19       3       989     51.4     41.6
```

The data is essentially multidimensional with GameTime, PlayId, and PlayerId as independent variables and x-coord and y-coord as dependent variables. How can I go about calculating the maximum distance from the nearest defender during the course of a play?

My guess is I would have to create columns containing the distance from each defender for each offensive player, but I don't know how to name those and be able to account for an unknown amount of defensive/offensive players (the full data set contains thousands of players).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution , I think there is a way to making it more efficient :

Assuming you have a dataframe called offense_df and a dataframe called defense_df:

In the merged dataframe you'll get the answer to your question, basically it will create the following dataframe:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance 
merged_dataframe = pd.merge(offense_df,defense_df,on=['GameTime','PlayId'],suffixes=('_off','_def'))
```

```
    GameTime    PlayId  PlayerId_off    x-coord_off y-coord_off PlayerId_def    x-coord_def y-coord_def
0   1   1   751 30.2    15.0    117 20.2    20.0
1   1   1   751 30.2    15.0    555 40.1    17.0
2   1   1   419 41.3    15.0    117 20.2    20.0
3   1   1   419 41.3    15.0    555 40.1    17.0
4   1   1   989 10.1    15.0    117 20.2    20.0
```

The next two lines are here to create a unique column for the coordinates , basically it will create for the offender (coord_off) and the defender a column (coord_def) that contains a tuple (x,y) this will simplify the computation of the distance.

```
merged_dataframe['coord_off'] = merged_dataframe.apply(lambda x: (x['x-coord_off'], x['y-coord_off']),axis=1)
merged_dataframe['coord_def'] = merged_dataframe.apply(lambda x: (x['x-coord_def'], x['y-coord_def']),axis=1)
```

We compute the distance to all the defender at a given GameTime,PlayId.

```
merged_dataframe['distance_to_def'] = merged_dataframe.apply(lambda x: distance.euclidean(x['coord_off'],x['coord_def']),axis=1)
```

For each PlayerId,GameTime,PlayId we take the distance to the nearest defender.

```
smallest_dist = merged_dataframe.groupby(['GameTime','PlayId','PlayerId_off'])['distance_to_def'].min()
```

Finally we take the maximum distance (of these minimum distances) for each PlayerId.

```
smallest_dist.groupby('PlayerId_off').max()
```